# Android Studio Plugin Backup?

Tags: android-studio, plugins, backup, settings

Is there any software or plugin to take backup of Android Studio plugins? There is settings repository but it only takes backup of settings and not plugin names.

Comment: I'm not so sure if backing up `~/.AndroidStudio3.2/config/plugins` is enough...

Comment: I also don't know particularly , but deleting that surely deletes everything.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to backup the whole folder of `~/.AndroidStudio<version>/config/plugins`. Moving it to another computer with a fresh installed Android Studio will recover all the plugins you installed.

For settings inside plugins, go to `~/.AndroidStudio<version>/config/options`.

Also, it is cross-platformed, for example, you can backup in your Linux and recover in Windows.

Comment: I know about the folder now, but is there any automated tool for that out there? as you know the folders contain so many small files which are very slow when transferring to different location.

Comment: @RaghavSatyadev For JetBrains IDE, there is an option of [Sync Plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#sync-plugins), however this option doesn't exist in **Android Studio** or earlier version of JetBrains IDE...

Comment: Just saw that option, but it requires a JetBrains account. it could have been better if there was an option to sync plugin settings also in settings repository.